# java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse

Tags: java, android

this is main activity java class

```
public  class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse,View.OnClickListener {

    EditText etusername,etpassword;
    Button btnlogin;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
        etpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(this,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        HashMap postData = new HashMap();

        postData.put("txtUsername", etusername.getText().toString());
        postData.put("txtPassword", etpassword.getText().toString() );

        PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(this, (AsyncResponse) postData);
        task.execute("http://10.0.3.2/client/login.php");
    }
}
```

in xml file i have three fields.. username password and login button.
after clicking button , it says app currently stopped!
im using android phone t run my app!

Comment: Yeah ! Your error clearly says that what you need to do.

Comment: and that is obvious that it can't be cast. Please add some context of why you need it, what you are trying to do, etc.

Comment: i have a simple login app... so, after clicking the login button it says app unfortunately stopped and i found the error which i mentioned in title in logcat!

Comment: Please post the entire code and ur requirement

Comment: "http://10.0.3.2/client/login.php" this is used for zenymotion right...im using android phn to run my app, so should i use 10.0.2.2?

Comment: add the code for PostResponseAsyncTask class

Comment: I asked u to post the PostResponseAsyncTask class not the activity

Comment: there is no such class.. i have follwed a youtube tutorial [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4eFBQmWs8Q&lc=z12bitkydmuht1z3a23vhxkwuqnfxvaxc04.1495694127844323] and he havent told what to code in that class.. he  included one libraryfrom here [https://github.com/kosalgeek/generic_asynctask_v2]

Comment: implement the changes as i did in my answer @AKHILAK

Comment: where did you change your answer?! i didn't get you ??!! @Roy

Comment: check the code inside OnClick...

Comment: i changed like this new PostResponseAsyncTask(this,postData,this);

Comment: the error is related to hashmap i guess! help please!1

Comment: did u change and try???

Comment: the error is solved through my answer, error comes since ur casting hashmap to Async Response,i just resolved it

Comment: can you suggest a good tutorial to get a better idea on this? and error is gone, but though my values are correct still it is showing that login failed ! @Roy

Comment: post the log cat.. i have no knowledge on tutorials,i would rather suggest going back to the Java basics before coming into android,since it seems u do not have an idea about casting n stuff like that

Comment: 05-25 08:47:30.162 24319-24735/com.example.akhila.androidphpmysql D/PostResponseAsyncTask: IOException Error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.3.2 (port 80) after 15000ms

Answer (score 0):

I went through the library which u provided,U need to Change it Like this :

```
public  class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse,View.OnClickListener {

    EditText etusername,etpassword;
    Button btnlogin;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etusername);
        etpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpassword);
        btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        btnlogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(this,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        HashMap postData = new HashMap();

        postData.put("txtUsername", etusername.getText().toString());
        postData.put("txtPassword", etpassword.getText().toString() );

        PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(this,postData,this);
        task.execute("http://10.0.3.2/client/login.php");
    }
}
```